# How to find multiple records(attendance) of same date with alias of same table in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, self-join

I have a table named rjs_attendance with following four column

```
_________________________________________________
|attenedance_id | admin_id | note | created_date|
-------------------------------------------------
```

A user can make attendance several times in a day. Odd entry is assumed as sign in and even entry is assumed as sign out.
The output I need looks something like this.

```
_______________________________________________________________________________  
|admin_id   | time_in  | time_in_note  | time_out | time_out_note | date      |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1          |10:00     | none          | 11:00    | none          | 2015-12-24|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|1          |11:30     |none           |12:15     |none           | 2015-12-24|
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I'm not able to fetch all record of the same date, but I'm able to fecth one record of the same date.
The query I have run is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    `atd_in`.`admin_id` AS `admin_id`,
    CAST(MIN(`atd_in`.`created_date`) AS TIME) AS `time_in`,
    `atd_in`.`note` AS `time_in_note`,
    CAST(MAX(`atd_out`.`created_date`) AS TIME) AS `time_out`,
    `atd_out`.`note` AS `time_out_note`,
    CAST(`atd_in`.`created_date` AS DATE) AS `date_on` 
FROM 
    `zf2`.`rjs_attendance` `atd_in` 
    LEFT JOIN `zf2`.`rjs_attendance` `atd_out` 
        ON
            `atd_in`.`admin_id` = `atd_out`.`admin_id`
            AND CAST(`atd_in`.`created_date` AS DATE) = CAST(`atd_out`.`created_date` AS DATE) 
            AND `atd_in`.`attendance_id` <> `atd_out`.`attendance_id`
GROUP BY 
    CAST(`atd_in`.`created_date` AS DATE), `atd_in`.`admin_id`
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: provide some sample data (rjs_attendance) it should have both odd and even numbers of entries to cater for your use cases (but it does not have to be a large volume of data)

Comment: It looks to me like it should return all pairs of rows on the same date. BTW, you can use `DATE(created_date)` and `TIME(created_date)` to get the time and date out of a datettime.

Comment: @Used_By_Already  please find the some record in image: http://s11.postimg.org/ke2dkduqr/Untitled.png

Comment: @AhmadAsjad We can't copy and paste from an image.

Comment: The problem is with using `MIN()` and `MAX()`. That just gives you one row for each `admin_id` and date.

Comment: @Barmar Please find this link for some data and structure: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14ff5/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT A.admin_id, 
       MAX(IF(A.ID % 2 = 1, CAST(A.created_date AS TIME), NULL)) AS time_in, 
       MAX(IF(A.ID % 2 = 1, note, NULL)) AS time_in_note, 
       MAX(IF(A.ID % 2 = 0, CAST(A.created_date AS TIME), NULL)) AS time_out, 
       MAX(IF(A.ID % 2 = 0, note, NULL)) AS time_out_note, 
       CAST(A.created_date AS DATE) AS date_on 
FROM (SELECT IF(@adminId=@adminId:=A.admin_id, @id:=@id+1, @id:=1) AS ID, 
             A.admin_id, A.note, A.created_date 
      FROM zf2.rjs_attendance A, (SELECT @id:=1, @adminId:=0) AS B
      ORDER BY A.admin_id, A.attendance_id
    ) AS A
GROUP BY A.admin_id, CAST(A.created_date AS DATE), CEILING(A.ID / 2);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/14ff5/4)

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS time_in, 
       MAX(IF(A.ID % 2 = 1, note, NULL) AS time_in_note, 
       ' at line 2

Comment: I do it all the time, too.

Comment: Thanks @SaharshShah and Barmar

Answer (score 1):

before seeing any code - if you assume odd and even as entry and exit => join on this condition -

```
on A.id +1 = B.id
```

or

```
`atd_in`.`attendance_id` +1 = `atd_out`.`attendance_id`
```

you can even leave it left joined for non exit entries
(ids should be numerical of course)

if your records are not sorted this way, just reissue the ids column after sorting with order by and make new id column

Comment: This table contains multiple user, so it is possible that all the entries for admin user not in sequence

Comment: Anyway I go the answer of @SaharshShah. But thanks for your effort

Comment: Fine :) @SaharshShah answer is far more complete of course, although i would suggest to try it after re-issuing ids... it will make the code a lot clearer and compact imho